# Dynamic href generation on link click based on radio button state : PHP interaction with javascript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, codeigniter, jquery

I am using MVC framework in codeigniter and I have a view where I have this link (please note that `href` value is generated by call to a PHP function which in turn takes `'auth/mylogin'` as a parameter:

```
<a href = "<?php echo $this->FrontController->myLoginURL(site_url() . 'auth/mylogin'); ?>"> CLICK ME</a>
```

Now I have a radio button on the same view page.

```
<input id="ut1" name="usertype" type="radio" value="ut1"<?php echo set_radio('usertype', 'ut1', TRUE); ?> />
<label for="ut1" onclick="">User Type 1</label>

<input id="ut2" name="usertype" type="radio" value="ut2"<?php echo set_radio('usertype', 'ut2'); ?> />  
<label for="ut2" onclick="">User Type 2</label>
```

**Now what I want is this:** I want to pass the user type value in addition. What I mean is that depending on which radio button the user has chosen before he clicks the link, I want the code to be:

**User Type 1 radio selected before clicking CLICK ME**

```
<a href = "<?php echo $this->FrontController->myLoginURL(site_url() . 'auth/mylogin/ut1'); ?>"> CLICK ME</a>
```

**User Type 2 radio selected before clicking CLICK ME**

```
<a href = "<?php echo $this->FrontController->myLoginURL(site_url() . 'auth/mylogin/ut2'); ?>"> CLICK ME</a>
```

Since there is not submit, I assume I have to use *javascript* to do this.
But since *javascript* is client side and PHP serverside, I am not sure how to get this done.

How do I achieve this?
Please note that the code has been stripped to show only the relevant part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <label for="ut2" onclick="messi_fan('ut2');">User Type 2</label>
    <label for="ut1" onclick="messi_fan('ut1');">User Type 1</label>
<a id = "link" href = "<?php echo $this->FrontController->myLoginURL(site_url() . 'auth/mylogin'); ?>"> CLICK ME</a>
<script>

function messi_fan(type){
url = " <?php echo $this->FrontController->myLoginURL(site_url() . 'auth/mylogin/'; ?>";
new_url = url+type;
$("#link").attr('href',new_url);
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for, but this gives me the right direction to pursue. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **jQuery** like this:

```
    $('#container_id input[type=radio]').each(function(){
    rad=$(this);
    rad.click(function(e){
    #get new url from PHP
$.get ("file_that_returns your_url.php?user_type="+rad.val(), function(data) {
$("#yourlinkid_here").attr("href", data);
});
    # $("#yourlinkid_here").attr("href", $("#yourlinkid_here").attr("href")+rad.val());
    });

    });
```

Comment: #container_id  -is the parent of the radio btns;  
#yourlinkid_here -is the id of the link you want to change

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a question though: In the href attribute, I am calling the php function echo $this->FrontController->myLoginURL() whose argument has to be changed using javascript. I am new to javascript and I don't know where in your code snippet I can do this?

Comment: what kind of urls does the $this->FrontController->myLoginURL() generate ? Do they contain any kind of generated session token ? or the only part that differs between them is the user type ?

Comment: If  the generated URL is unique (you can't generate it in JavaScript using the user type and the previous href) you can try doing an AJAX call to a PHP file that will return the generated URL and use that as the href.